# Select with "loop while" with agroupment of values

Tags: sql-server

( sorry for my poor english at first! )

I have a table with a few fields like this

```
PK      Name1    Name2       Value    
1       nmAA     nm2AAA      01A
2       nmAA     nm2AAA      01B
3       nmAA     nm2AAA      01c
```

I need to have this result

```
Name1    Name2       ValueList
nmAA     nm2AAA      01A, 01B, 01c
```

I'm thinking in a loop that puts in a variable ( ValueList ) the results of the Value field. I don't know how to do this in SQL SERVER.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`FOR XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function to do that:

```
SELECT 
  t1.Name1,
  t1.name2,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t2.Value
    FROM Table1 t2
    WHERE t2.Name1 = t1.Name1
      AND t2.Name2 = t1.Name2
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS [Values]
FROM Table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.Name1, 
         t1.Name2;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca3b7/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (PK INT,Name1 VARCHAR(20),Name2 VARCHAR(20),Value VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES    
(1,'nmAA','nm2AAA','01A'),
(2,'nmAA','nm2AAA','01B'),
(3,'nmAA','nm2AAA','01c')


SELECT DISTINCT Name1, Name2, STUFF(ValueList, 1 ,2 , '') AS ValueList
FROM @t t 
        CROSS APPLY (
                     SELECT ', '+ Value [text()]
                     FROM @t
                     WHERE Name1 = t.Name1 
                     AND   Name2 = t.Name2
                     FOR XML PATH('')
                    )Q(ValueList)
```

**Result Set**

```
Name1   Name2   ValueList
nmAA    nm2AAA  01A, 01B, 01c
```